# How can I rename multiple pictures simultaneously?

Tags: finder, macbook-pro

For example,I have 20 pictures downloaded from the Internet. They have some crazy names like "XFGHDHR345" or "SDEREWQ230", and I want to name them:

"Picture 1"
"Picture 2"
"Picture 3"
"Picture 4"
"Picture 5"
.....
"Picture 20"

I don't want to type them one by one. I want to change their names at once.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For those who have Photoshop, it does a really nice job at easily doing just this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the built-in tool "Automator", you can define a workflow to batch rename files.

To do that, you will have to:

1. Open **Automator** *find it using Spotlight or in /Applications*
2. Create a new **Workflow**
3. Type get into the search field [image]
4. Scroll to the bottom of the list of items and drag **Get Specified Item** from the **Files & Folders** actions list on the left panel and drop it into the right panel
5. Click the **Add** button and find your files
6. Add the **Sort Finder Items** action followed by **Rename Finder Items**
7. It the **"Rename Finder Items"** panel, select **"Make Sequential"** and **"Add number to"** *Picture*
8. Hit the **play** button and you should be done

Have a look [here](http://macs.about.com/od/diyguidesprojects/ss/Using-Automator-to-Rename-Files.htm) or [here](http://macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/batch-rename-multiple-files.php) for an example tutorials on your specific renaming task at hand. An excellent overview of what Automator does and how powerful (and simple) it can be as a personal assistant - see the web page http://macosxautomation.com/automator/index.html

Comment: Nice example of Automator - it's clearly intended for this case to clean up photo files. I'll add in the grandfather of Automator resources, Sal Saghoian's http://macosxautomation.com/automator/index.html

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can use Terminal:

1. Move all your pictures to a temporary folder on the Desktop, for example  `Temp`.
2. Open Applications>Utilities>Terminal.app.
3. Change directory to `Temp`:

   ```
   cd ~/Desktop/Temp
   ```

   where `~` is expanded to your home directory (that is, `/Users/<yourusername>`.)
4. Run this compound shell command:

   ```
   n=1; for file in *; do mv "$file" "Picture $n"; let n++; done
   ```

   where:

   - `for ...; do ...; done` loops over your 20 files. `file` is the variable that holds filenames. See [this article](http://linux.about.com/od/Bash_Scripting_Solutions/a/How-To-Write-Bash-For-Loops.htm) for more information.
   - `n`, initially set to 1 and increased by one in every iteration with `let n++`, is the integer suffix for the renamed files.
   - `mv "$file" "Picture $n"` renames the files. `$n` is the value of variable `n`.

   The shell command is equivalent to:

   ```
   mv SDEREWQ230 "Picture 1"
   mv XFGHDHR345 "Picture 2"
   mv YWUU7738DT "Picture 3"
   (...)
   ```

For more information on the bash shell see [man bash](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/bash.1.html). For more information on shell scripting see this [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/opensource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html) at the Apple developer website.

Comment: This is a much better explanation of using the shell to handle file edits than [we have over there](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75114/any-easy-way-to-search-for-replace-characters-in-jpg-file-names-in-a-folder). Granted, that example is a simple edit - all files with pattern ABC need to be renamed to 123 so this has to be slightly more complex. +2 if I had two votes.

Comment: @Jadav I don't think you're counting keystrokes correctly here. Even if you key around the Finder and hit Enter on each instead of clicking, it's still more efficient to run the script, even if you're only doing 20 pictures.

Comment: Compared to the Automator solution ! But newer than less that is some impressive programing on your side.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to zero-pad the numbers or if the files have different extensions:

```
i=1; for f in *; do mv "$f" Picture\ $(printf %03d $i).${f#*.}; let i++; done
```

More examples:

```
# lowercase (Bash 4) and replace spaces with underscores
for f in *; do f2=${f,,}; mv "$f" "${f2// /_}"; done

# number based on modification date
IFS=$'\n'; i=1; for f in $(ls -rt *.jpg); do mv "$f" $(printf %04d $i).jpg; let i++; done

# file-5.jpg to file-005.jpg
for f in *; do b=${f%.*}; x=${f#*.}; mv "$f" "${b%-*}-$(printf %03d ${b#*-}).$x"; done
```

Comment: HOLA @Lauri Ranta, was that English :), or is the computer going up in smoke after doing that to it ?

Answer (score 4):

If you have Yosemite, it is built into Finder. Just select the files, rightclick and choose "Rename *n* files". Then change the dropdown to "Filter" and voila! You have batch renaming options!

Comment: Wow! Hadn't noticed that one yet. Also includes options for adding text, and some fancier formatting actions. Operation is undoable by Finder.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this. I can't believe it took only 1.5 seconds to rename about 50 images. Then, @badabamn, that solution was even quicker!!! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use the Terminal or Automator, there are commercial apps with a GUI for doing this. One is [A Better Finder Rename](http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/), which has a free trial version.

Comment: +1 for ABFR -- while it does cost $20, it quite easily handles this particular task, where the initial filenames are random, and many other more complex batch renaming tasks besides.

Comment: I always like to point out the option of using commercial utility apps with a nice GUI because many casual users find that using the Terminal or Automator is too difficult for some tasks. ABFR is an example of a refined product that is very flexible and works well. For many users, spending $20 is a better option than learning the complexities of rarely-used text commands. You can decide which you would rather use.

Answer (score 3):

I will recommend here [NameChanger](http://namechanger.en.softonic.com/mac) application. Its very simple and fast to use.
Very good options given there for renaming files with different criteria.